# Is the formula for residence time equivalent to Little's Law?

Tags: queueing-theory

Is the equation T=M/F where T is residence time, M is quantity and F is flow rate equivalent to W=L/lambda where W is waiting time, L is queue length and lambda is flow rate?  It seems to me that the derivation of either equation would be equivalent to the derivation of the other.

Comment: Parcels arrive to a control volume, have some residence time, then exit. Customers arrive to a queue, have some sojourn time, and then exit. The same fundamental idea is being expressed with different words here.